# Ares 5 and SLS relation

Tags: rockets

I'm having an online discussion regarding these rockets. I'm being told that I'm wrong to think of the SLS as a continuation of the Ares 5. That the SLS is a completely different rocket, and so it's not fair to add the Ares 5 expense to the SLS budget. That cost wise SLS  is 'a steal' at only 16 billion, compared to 30 billion for the Saturn 5, and is the most cost effective heavy launch rocket NASA
has produced. Would anyone like to contribute?